# Why use private variables with properties - Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, variables, properties

A introduce

If you make all your properties virtual then EF will generate proxy classes at runtime that derives from your POCO classed, these proxies allow EF to find out about changes in real time rather than having to capture the original values of your object and then scan for changes when you save (this is obviously has performance and memory usage benefits but the difference will be negligible unless you have a large number of entities loaded into memory). These are known as 'change tracking proxies', if you make your navigation properties virtual then a proxy is still generated but it is much simpler and just includes some logic to perform lazy loading when you access a navigation property.

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/99d8d4a1-5ab1-42dc-b9db-5087be02162d

[1]

```
public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }
```

[2]

```
private ICollection<Log> _logs;
public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs 
{ 
    get 
       {
         if(_logs == null) Logs = new HashSet<Log>();
         return Logs ;
       }
    private set {} 
}
```

[3]

```
private ICollection<Log> _logs;
public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs 
{ 
    get 
       {
         if(_logs == null) _logs = new HashSet<Log>();
         return _logs;
       }
    set {_logs = value; }
}
```

How is better thinking in EF - Code first?

Why some people use private fields with properties?

private set can be help to avoid modify the full list

In [1] we can have null references, forcing verify if is null before use the property

But, private variables/fields, I not understand why is necessary. I think propertys in "backend" generate private fields, so?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, in [1] you can have a null reference exception (usually when you create a new parent class and then you add a new Log.
An approach to avoid it is to:
- write [2]
- initialize it in the parent class constructor
- with c# 5 you can write

```
public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; } = new new HashSet<Log>();
```

The [3] is not usefull (if you initialize Logs property, EF do not need to access to setter).

Another interesting thing is that you can use your own collection i.e.

```
public class LogCollection : ObservableCollection<Log>
{
    public Post Add(string content)
    {
        Log log = new Log
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Content = content
        };
        Add(log);
        return log;
    }
}
```

and then use it in the master class instead of ICollection, i.e.

```
public virtual LogCollection Logs 
{ 
    get 
       {
         if(_logs == null) Logs = new HashSet<Log>();
         return Logs ;
       };
    private set; 
}
```

Usually I initialize collections in class constructor, I don't use backing field and my setter is public (but probably I never used it outside the parent class so it's a stupid way to implement it). But it's my way of work with c# 4.x

**EDIT**
About a part of your question, EF does not use backing fields, it access only to property setter and getter. You can force to use private backing fields (map backing fields) mapping it via fluent interface and mapping it in an inner class.